# Как писать join без select в MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Пошёл на собеседование, задали такой вопрос: "как писать join без select". По-моему так не возможно, естественно я писал select ... И в то же время сказали, что неправильно, если это возможно писать. Покажите пример, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может имелось ввиду «update .... join ...”

Comment: не знаю даже не сказал правильный ответ

Comment: join - часть from. Т.е. Может быть также и в delete, и в update запросах

Comment: А ещё БД, таблицу или поле можно назвать `\`join\``. Формально условие выполнено - `JOIN` есть (даже в DDL или в `USE`), а `SELECT` - нет.

Comment: пожалуйста дайте пример

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
UPDATE TABLEA a 
   JOIN TABLEB b ON a.join_colA = b.join_colB  
   SET a.columnToUpdate = [something]
```

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОООООООЕ спасибо