# КАК С ПОМОЩЬЮ SELECT - а найти первые 15 `String` и

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица, в которой есть раздел text, в нем написано допустим `" Hello my name is ... "`. Как получить первые 15 String - и с помощью SELECT

Comment: Переведите вопрос на русский, пожалуйста.

Comment: как найти первые 15 - String и с помощью SELECT : B MYSQL - STRING по моему значит character  извините я не mysql разработчик...надо писать QUERY который может найти первые 15 буквы или цифры  ну так думаю понято объяснил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> есть таблица, в котором есть раздел text, в нем написано допустим это" Hello my name is ... " как получить первые 15 String - и с помощью SELECT

Вот такая команда:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(string, position, length) FROM YOU_TABLE_NAME ;
```

- *postion* - начинается с 1
- *length* - длина строки

---

**UPD:**

**Дано:** таблица следующего вида.

```
create table users (
    id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR(50),
    last_name VARCHAR(50),
    descr VARCHAR(255)
);
```

**Задача:** получить, строку от начала до 15 символов, столбца: `descr`

**Решение:** Вполняем команду.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(descr, 1, 15) from users;
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: ребят извините но не знаю либо я не то пишу либо не работает вариант вот я сделаю так   `SELECT SUBSTRING(string, position, length) FROM example ;` и он в консоль дает ошибка типо String раздел не нашел и когда я ставлю место  string-а имя раздела, position - а ставлю 0, length - ставлю 15 он в консоль нечего не дает что мне делать помогите пожалуйста

Comment: спасибо уважаемый

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849908/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-join-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-select-%D0%B2-mysql?noredirect=1#comment1367455_849908 если можно можешь ответить на эту вопросу пожалуйста

Comment: если конечно знаешь ответ если нет все таки благодарю тебя